# RSACryptoServiceProvider.VerifyData exception in line 326

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I have a problem with using RSACryptoServiceProvider.VerifyData

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object
>   System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.VerifyData
>   (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Object halg, System.Byte[] signature)
>   (at
>   /Applications/buildAgent/work/3df08680c6f85295/mcs/class/corlib/System.Security.Cryptography/RSACryptoServiceProvider.cs:326)

You can see exception raised in the RSACryptoServiceProvider.cs line 326
I double checked all params and creation of rsa -- everything ok.
Any ideas ?

my code:

```
X509Certificate2 x509 = null;
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = null;
byte[] certificate = Convert.FromBase64String( certificate_s );
x509 = new X509Certificate2( certificate );
rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider) x509.PublicKey.Key;
bool sha1Valid = rsa.VerifyData( data, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1"), signature );
```

Comment: Which line is 326? What is `certificate_s`, `data` and `signature`?

Comment: The Unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Answer (score 3):

Solved.
Error caused by halg param -- CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1")
Seems it is illegal in Unity C# scripting
HashAlgorithm.Create("SHA1") must be used instead